# Transferring values from a char array to an integer array in C programming

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I am having the following problem. I have created a char array which represents a series of characters and numbers - this was designed to model a string read or got from a text file. I wish to then search this string using the "search" function defined below, pulling out only the numbers before 'H' and assigning to a separately defined integer array. I find when I use gdb, this function works fine. However, only part of the array is ever returned - the first 8 elements to be exact. Would anyone please be able to explain why this is from looking at the code below?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void search(char buffer[], int size, int array[]);

int main (void)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); 

    buffer[0] = 2;
    buffer[1] = 'H';
    buffer[2] = 3;
    buffer[3] = 'H';  
    buffer[4] = 6;
    buffer[5] = 'H'; 
    buffer[6] = 4; 
    buffer[7] = 'H'; 
    buffer[8] = 6; 
    buffer[9] = 'H';
    buffer[10] = 7;
    buffer[11] = 'H';
    buffer[12] = 11;
    buffer[13] = 'H';
    buffer[14] = 12;
    buffer[15] = 'H';
    buffer[16] = 17;
    buffer[17] = 'H'; 

    int* array ;    
    array = malloc(sizeof(buffer) * sizeof(int));  

    search(buffer, sizeof(buffer), array); 

    for(int i = 0, n = sizeof(array); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    } 

    free(array); 
}

void search(char buffer[], int size, int array[])
{
    int position = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == 'H')
        {
            *(array + position) = buffer[i-1];
            position++;
        }
    }       
}
```

The compiler outputs the following:

```
array[0] = 2
array[1] = 3
array[2] = 6
array[3] = 4
array[4] = 6
array[5] = 7
array[6] = 11
array[7] = 12
```

which as can be seen is missing the ninth position in the array - value 17. In fact, if I fgets into a buffer a much bigger set of numbers and 'H's, I am always returned an array of size 8. Why is this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are passing `sizeof(buffer)` to `search()`, NOT the number of elements you have used - 18.

Comment: `buffer[i-1];` is Undefined Behaviour when `i == 0`

Comment: @WeatherVane `sizeof(buffer)` means  number of elements of the `array`.  `buffer[i-1];` if `(buffer[i] == 'H')`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY please read my comments more carefully.

Comment: @WeatherVane You do not need to pass the number of elements that you are using. when `i == 0`, will not be access to the `buffer[i-1]`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you would if one of the elements was 0, as opposed to the default `memset` 0. Also, `buffer[i-1]` won't be hit for this *specific data set* but it's careless.

Comment: `"The compiler outputs the following"` - no it doesn't. The compiler outputs object code, which in turn is linked by the linker into an executable image. When you run this image on your machine, it outputs "the following".

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is with

```
n = sizeof(array)
```

`array` being a pointer, `sizeof(array)` will give you the size of the pointer (as `sizeof(array)` here is *essentially* `sizeof(int *)`, which seems to be 8 for your platform), not the cumulative size (or number of elements) in the `array`.

One possible way to get what you want will be the `search()` to return the count of element put into the `array` and use that return value in the `for` loop for printing the required elements from `array`.

Comment: Hi thanks, you are absolutely right and this worked a treat! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `n = sizeof(array)` with `n = strlen(buffer) / 2` will do (you want `n` to be the number of filled elements in the array).

Btw,

- You need to make sure the `buffer` always has correct pairs.
- Would be safer to declare the buffer like this `char buffer[1000] = "";`
- "I am always returned an array of size 8" - that's because `sizeof(int)` in 64b-machine is 8 bytes, which is what you got from `sizeof(array)` - as `array` here is pointer.